# How to properly read a value from a JSON in Angular 6

Tags: angular, web, client, angular6

I despair again and simply cannot reach a result, because everyone has this problem in a different context.

I am trying to load a value from a JSON response object and output it into an html input field. The problem is, however, that the value I load is always defined as 'undefined' by the console.

So my question now is: how do I properly read a value from a JSON object?

The method affected is the `updateEinsatzort()`

Notice: I am totally new to WebDevelopment and TypeScript.

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EinsatzorteService } from '../einsatzorte.service'
import { EinsatzortModel } from '../einsatzortmodel'
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-einsatzorte',
  templateUrl: './einsatzorte.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./einsatzorte.component.css']
})
export class EinsatzorteComponent implements OnInit {

  einsatzorte$: Object;
  model = new EinsatzortModel(null,'','','','','','','','','','');
  einsatzortObjekt$: EinsatzortModel;

  constructor(private einsatzorte: EinsatzorteService, private einsatzorteServ: EinsatzorteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.einsatzorte.getEinsatzorte().subscribe(
      einsatzorte => this.einsatzorte$ = einsatzorte
    )
  }

  newEinsatzort(form: NgForm) {

    var einsatzortObjekt={
      institutionsart: form.value.institutionsart,
      name: form.value.name,
      adresse: form.value.adresse,
      plz: form.value.plz,
      stadt: form.value.stadt,
      land: form.value.land,
      tel: form.value.tel
    }

    this.einsatzorte.createEinsatzorte(einsatzortObjekt).subscribe(
      (response) => {console.log(response);}
    );


  window.location.reload()

  }


  deleteEinsatzort(id): void{
    this.einsatzorte.deleteEinsatzort(id)
    .subscribe(dataErsatz => {
      this.einsatzorte$ = this.einsatzorte$;
    })

    window.location.reload()
  }

  updateEinsatzort(id: number, einsatzort: EinsatzortModel){
    this.einsatzorteServ.readEinsatzort(id, einsatzort).subscribe(
      updateObjekt => {
        this.einsatzortObjekt$ = this.einsatzortObjekt$;
        console.log(updateObjekt) // Gives me whole object with correct values
        console.log() //<<<<===== here I want to have the <<name>> attribute of this value
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**Model**

```
export class EinsatzortModel {

    constructor(

    public id:number,
    public institutionsart: string,
    public name: string,
    public adresse: string,
    public plz: string,
    public stadt: string,
    public land: string,
    public ansprechpartner: string,
    public tel: string,
    public mobil: string,
    public mail: string

    ){}
}
```

**service.ts**

```
  readEinsatzort(id: Number, einsatzort: EinsatzortModel){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/einsatzort/einsatzort?id=' + id, einsatzort)
  }
```

Comment: I assume the code to read the values are actually in your service (EinsatzorteService)? Could you post that as well?

Comment: @DeborahK updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to read using POST and not GET? My Angular v6 code to get data looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Using the generic parameter on the get: `get<IProduct[]>` maps the result to the defined interface.

But if you want to stick with the style you have, you could try just strongly typing your return value and post:

```
  readEinsatzort(id: Number, einsatzort: EinsatzortModel): Observable<EinsatzortModel>{
    return this.http.post<EinsatzortModel>('http://localhost:8080/einsatzort/einsatzort?id=' + id, einsatzort)
  }
```

Then you should be able to read the value like this:

```
console.log(updateObjekt.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two option:

1.) In html you need to add this for example

```
<div>{{einsatzortObjekt?.name}}</div>
```

with this your code will not break if name is undefined

2.) Create empty domain object, so attribute will not be undefined

**Model**

```
export class EinsatzortModel {
  id: number
  institutionsart: string
  name: string

  constructor( id?: number, institutionsart?: string, name?: string){
    this.id = id
    this.institutionsart = institutionsart
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

**Component ts**

```
export class EinsatzorteComponent implements OnInit {

  einsatzorte$: Object;
  model = new EinsatzortModel(); // Create empty model

  ...
```

**Component html**

```
<div>{{einsatzortObjekt.name}}</div>
```

Now name will not be undefined